# How to update a class variable in a method in Python so that its value is accessible from other classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

How do I update the value of a class variable, so that when importing that class in another class, it has the updated value? It seems that editing the class variable's value only edits it for that specific instance of the class. For example

```
class Test():
  state = "Disconnected"

def connected:
  self.__class__.state = "Connected" 
#I also tried referring to the variable as Test.state and self.state
```

another file:

```
from Test import *

class TestTool:

def initialize_run_GUI(self):
  testClient = TestClient()
  
  state = tk.Label(text=test.state) #I also tried Test.state
```

After pressing a button that calls `connected` (updating the value of `state` to "Connected" in Test), calling test.state or Test.state from TestTool still returns "Disconnected"

Comment: `text=test.state` reads the value once and passes that value to `Label` once. It does not establish any sort of permanent connection between `Label` and `test.state`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah just realized that that was my issue. Do you know how to create a binding so that it gets the updated value with tkinter?